# joint distribution, probability, calculating probabilities under false independent assumption, when the random variables are actually dependent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, independence

Suppose I have random variables $X,Y,Z$ and I would like to compute the probability that random variable $X$ is smaller than $Y$ and $Z$:

$$
\pi_X 
\overset{def}{=} Pr(X < Y, X < Z)
= \int Pr(x < Y,x < Z)dPr(X\le x)
$$
Define $\pi_Y$ and $\pi_Z$ similarly and without loss of generality, let $\pi_X \le \pi_Y \le \pi_Z$. I know that $X,Y$ and $Z$ are positively associated.
Suppose that I compute $\pi_X$ "falsely" assuming that $Z \perp Y$ using the formula below:

$$
\pi^{ind}_X = \int Pr(x < Y)Pr(x < Z)dPr(X\le x).
$$

I would like to know what condition I need for the the dependence structure among $X,Y$ and $Z$ (e.g., positive correlation?) to claim $\pi_X \ge \pi_X^{ind}$? I.e., the $\pi_X^{ind}$ under the (false) independence assumption always underestimates the chance that $X$ is smaller than both $Y$ and $Z$.

Based on the following small simulation study in R, I am guessing that $\pi_X \ge \pi_X^{ind}$ is true when $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are "positively" associated in some way. 
The simulation model assume that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are from the multivariate normal as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X\\
Y\\
Z
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
N_3\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
0\\
2
\end{bmatrix}
\sim
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2&\rho\sigma &\rho\sigma\\
\rho\sigma&    1    &\rho\\
\rho\sigma & \rho & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
$$
where I consider the values $\sigma=0.5,1,1.5,2$. Then I generate large enough samples from this multivariate distribution and computed $\pi_X$ based on the Monte Carlo samples.
I also computed $\pi_X^{ind}$ assuming the independence across $X,Y$ and $Z$. I see that regardless of the values of $\sigma$, the $\pi_X$ is always greater than $\pi_X^{ind}$ when $rho > 0$.

```
 library(mvtnorm)
 get.pi <- function(xyz)
   {
     ## obtain the MC estimate of pi^ind and pi
     xs <- xyz[,1]
     ys <- xyz[,2]
     zs <- xyz[,3]
     num.indp <- num.dp <- 0
     M <- length(xs)
     for (ix in 1 : M)
      {
       x.temp <- xs[ix]
       num.dp <- num.dp + mean(x.temp < ys & x.temp < zs)
       num.indp <- num.indp + mean(x.temp < ys)*mean(x.temp < zs)
      }
    return(list(indp=num.indp/M,dp=num.dp/M)) 
   }


 N <- 10000
 sds1 <- seq(0.5,2,0.5)
 sd2 <- 1
 sd3 <- 1
 rhos <- seq(0,1,0.05)
 mus <- c(-2,0,2)  
 cols <- c("red","green")
par(mfrow=c(2,length(sds1)/2),mar=c(2,2,2,2))
for (isd in 1 : length(sds1))
  {
   sd1 <-sds1[isd]
   res.indP <- res.noIndP <- rep(NA, length(rhos))
   for (irho in 1 : length(rhos))
    {
      rho <- rhos[irho]
      rho12 <- rho
      rho13 <- rho
      rho23 <- rho

      S <- matrix(c(sd1^2,sd1*sd2*rho12,sd1*sd3*rho13,
                   sd1*sd2*rho12,sd2^2,sd2*sd3*rho13,
                   sd1*sd3*rho13,sd2*sd3*rho13,sd3^2),3,3)

      xyz <- rmvnorm(N,mean=mus,sigma=S)
      re <- get.pi(xyz)
      res.indP[irho] <- re$indp
          res.noIndP[irho] <- re$dp
     }
    rang <- c(res.indP,res.noIndP)
    ylim <- c(min(rang),max(rang))
    plot(rhos,res.indP,type="l",col=cols[1],ylim=ylim,
         main=paste("sd1=",sd1,sep=""))
    points(rhos,res.noIndP,type="l",col=cols[2],ylim=ylim)
   }

legend("topright",c("Independent","No assumption"),col=cols,lwd=1)
```

Comment: I believe the answer will vary depending on the precise meaning of "positively associated."  What exactly do *you* mean by this?

Comment: @whuber I am actually looking which condition of "positive association" is required to satisfy $\pi_X \ge \pi_X^{ind}$...

Comment: You might want to emphasize that by editing your question.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the advice. I just edited my question.

Comment: This post in math.SE, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452484/distance-between-the-product-of-marginal-distributions-and-the-joint-distributio/456313#456313,  may be interesting as a more general treatment of such issues.

Comment: Already the first formula for $\pi_X$ is wrong in general (it assumes that $X$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$, a hypothesis which is explicitely negated in the next paragraph).